# Chaos with InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

Please clear this scenario.

I created a viewController named RootViewController,so obiviously we'll get RootViewController.h and RootViewController.m

Then i created  a nibfile named ViewScreen.xib  by selecting a newFile named viewXib, so automatically we'll get a View in the xibfile.And i linked FilesOwner class to RootViewController.

so if i want to set the back ground color of the view as "groupTableViewBackgroundColor" ,can't i set that in attributes inspector,is the only way to set that color to view is by doing manually in RootViewController.m(declaring a view and setting view.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]; can't we do the same by using interfaceBuilder.

if any one is interested to solve this ,please go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the colour palette to "Developer" you'll find the list of system colours, including the background colour for tables.

Comment: I can't find any color palette named "Developer" in Interface Builder. Can you clarify where this can be set?

Comment: Ah, I found this - it's on the "Color Palettes" tab of the Color Picker dialog (the middle of the five buttons at the top of that view). 

HOWEVER, I didn't find groupTableViewBackgroundColor there - rather it was under the "iPhone SDK" palette.

Comment: @IQpierce Yes, Apple keep moving it around and renaming it. In the current version (3.2.3) there's a drop-down next to the colour button; you don't have to click through to the colour picker itself.